# How to create a minimal foundation.js file

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

Just downloaded Foundation 6.2.3 in preparation for migrating a project from 5.5. There are pretty easy and clear instructions on how to create a custom `foundation.css` file to include just the components I need, but the same is not true for creating a custom `foundation.js` file. The one in the `dists/` direction contains ALL of the JavaScript code for foundation, even if I am not using a given component.

At first I thought it was a simple concatenation of the various smaller Javascript files in the `plugins/` directory, but that doesn't seem to be the case. For example, at the top of `dists/foundation.js` is stuff that looks suspiciously like the contents of `plugins/foundation.core.js` but there are differences. For example, `foundation.js` has version 6.2.3 whereas `foundation.core.js` has version 6.2.2. Removing the leading whitespace that seems to have been inserted into `foundation.js` and then doing a diff against `foundation.core.js` yields some differences. So clearly, the components required to build `foundation.js` are not included in the default source.

I would really like to be able to build a minimal `foundation.js` to accompany my minimal `foundation.css` file. Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Foundation 6.2.4
the correct loading order of the various javascript files should be:

```
foundation.core.js            
foundation.util.box.js    
foundation.util.keyboard.js    
foundation.util.mediaQuery.js                    
foundation.util.motion.js                            
foundation.util.nest.js        
foundation.util.timerAndImageLoader.js    
foundation.util.touch.js    
foundation.util.triggers.js                                                        
foundation.abide.js    
foundation.accordion.js    
foundation.accordionMenu.js            
foundation.drilldown.js    
foundation.dropdown.js    
foundation.dropdownMenu.js            
foundation.equalizer.js    
foundation.interchange.js    
foundation.magellan.js    
foundation.offcanvas.js    
foundation.orbit.js    
foundation.responsiveMenu.js    
foundation.responsiveToggle.js    
foundation.reveal.js    
foundation.slider.js    
foundation.sticky.js            
foundation.tabs.js    
foundation.toggler.js        
foundation.tooltip.js
```

These are the files needed for the various functionalities (the dependencies):

```
accordion:
  foundation.util.keyboard.js
  foundation.util.motion.js

accordionMenu:
  foundation.util.keyboard.js    
  foundation.util.motion.js    
  foundation.util.nest.js

drilldown:
      foundation.util.keyboard.js    
      foundation.util.motion.js    
      foundation.util.nest.js

dropdownMenu:
      foundation.util.keyboard.js    
      foundation.util.motion.js    
      foundation.util.box.js    
      foundation.util.nest.js

dropdown:
      foundation.util.keyboard.js    
      foundation.util.box.js    
      foundation.util.triggers.js

interchange:
      foundation.util.triggers.js    
      foundation.util.timerAndImageLoader.js

magellan:
      foundation.util.motion.js

offcanvas:
      foundation.util.motion.js    
      foundation.util.triggers.js

orbit:
      foundation.util.motion.js    
      foundation.util.timerAndImageLoader.js    
      foundation.util.keyboard.js    
      foundation.util.touch.js

responsiveMenu:
      foundation.util.triggers.js    
      foundation.util.mediaQuery.js    
      foundation.accordionMenu.js    
      foundation.drilldown.js    
      foundation.dropdownMenu.js    
      foundation.util.nest.js

responsiveToggle:
      foundation.util.mediaQuery.js

reveal:
      foundation.util.box.js    
      foundation.util.motion.js    
      foundation.util.triggers.js    
      foundation.util.mediaQuery.js

slider:
      foundation.util.triggers.js    
      foundation.util.motion.js    
      foundation.util.keyboard.js    
      foundation.util.touch.js

sticky:
      foundation.util.triggers.js    
      foundation.util.mediaQuery.js

tabs:
      foundation.util.keyboard.js    
      foundation.util.timerAndImageLoader.js

toggler:
      foundation.util.motion.js

tooltip:
      foundation.util.box.js    
      foundation.util.triggers.js    
      foundation.util.mediaQuery.js    
      foundation.util.motion.js

motion-ui:
      foundation.util.motion.js
```

Please note that in order to make the final file work you have to:

1) concatenate them

2) use Babel to "compile" the concatenated file (presets:es2015)

3) uglify it